# Cv2 y numpy, metodo ramdon.randint

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, sublimetext3, cv2

espero estén bien.

Estoy teniendo un problema con un programa que estoy haciendo, es la primera vez que uso Python y no es que sea un experto programando. Este es mi código.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

red = 0,0,255;

def mostrarImagen(nombre, imagen):
    cv2.imshow(nombre, imagen)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return

# CREATE IMG
canvas = np.zeros((500,500,3), dtype="uint8")
np.random.randint(0,10,30)

for i in range(0,25,1):
    cv2.circle(canvas,(250,250),150,red,-1)
    np.random.randint(0,10,30)
    #(250,250 Plano C)
    #(radio,color,relleno)



mostrarImagen("canvas", canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

La idea es que debe mostrarme en una imagen, la cual ya hice, y en ella debo mostrar una seria de círculos de manera aleatoria (Diámetro o radio, color y posición; dentro de la imagen negra). he probado de muchas formas, ojala puedan ayudarme. Me siento como payaso en funeral.

Answer (score 0):

iSony, revisa este código, y cuéntanos si es que es lo que necesitas, o si te faltó explicar alguna cosa.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from random import randint

def traerColor():
  return randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)

canvas = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), dtype="uint8")

for i in range(0, 5):
    cv2.circle(canvas,(randint(50, 450), randint(50, 450)), randint(5, 80), traerColor(), -1)

cv2.imshow("lienzo", canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Me puedes explicar que hace cada uno de los randint? no estoy entendiendo bien su funcionamiento.

Comment: La función randint entrega un número dentro de un rango, randint(0, 255), lo hace desde 0 hasta 255, o sea, dentro de los valores válidos para cada color RGB. En resumen, es un color al azar, en el caso de **trae Color**, y cuando lo uso dentro de **cv2.circle**, corresponde, en este orden, a los parámetros coordenada x, y, además de el radio del círculo.